# React Native ios Switch in FlatList not toggling after value changed

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, uiswitch

I am trying to toggle `ios` Switch in react native. But the switch comes back to initial position as soon as I change it.

What I have:

```
class ABC extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
           obj: []
        }
    }
    fetch(){
    // fetch something from remote server, set it to state object array
    }
    setStatus(id, value){
        var temp = [...this.state.obj]
        temp.map((t) => {
        if (t.id == id) {
            t.flag = value
        }
        })
        this.setState({ obj: temp })
    }
    render() {
        return (
        <View>
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.obj}
                renderItem={({ item }) =>
                    <View>
                        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                        <Switch
                            onValueChange={(val) => this.setStatus(item.id, val)}
                            value={item.flag}
                        />
                    </View>
                }
                keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id.toString()}
            />
        </View>
    );
    }
}
```

I logged the before and after value of `obj` state and they seem to update. Should the FlatList be rendered again (like a web page refresh) ? Or is there something I am missing ? Searched `SO` for answers, couldn't find my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Flatlist` has a prop called `extraData`.

This prop tells `Flatlist` whether to re-render or not.

If data in `extraData` changes then flatlist re-renders based on new data provided in `data` prop.

So whenever you need to re-render flatlist just change something in `extraData`.

Best way is to pass state to`extraData` which is passed to `Data`.

So, just pass `extraData={this.state.obj}`.

there also other way called `forceUpdate`.

you can call `this.forceUpdate()`.

but this is not recommended because this will render not only flatlist but entire component in which you are calling this.

Comment: Works. Except had to do this `extraData={this.state}` instead of `extraData={this.state.obj}`. Thanks a lot !!